# Send a POST and receive cookies in PHP

Tags: php, http, cookies

I have a website that needs to send a `POST` to a website, than read the cookies returned (in an HTTP way - aka Set-Cookie: ...)
I tried this code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.site.co.il/login.php?do=login');
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "datadata");
 $a = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

but it only loads the website in the browser (without me even writing `print($a)` !!!) - although it DOES show me 'connect successfully' - but ofcorse doesn't set the cookie.
I basically want to make a proxy-like application, where the cookies received from `site.co.il` would be stored on the clients machine, but each time it connects to my site, it will grab the cookies and do a POST to `site.co.il` with them.
Any example of grabbing the `Set-Cookie:` header from the returned HTTP will be appreciated.
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mihai is right. Here's some code that does it:
http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#92580

Answer (score 2):

try with `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to `true` and trim out `BODY` content

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init('http://www.site.co.il/login.php?do=login');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "datadata");
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    $a = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: but it still just posts to the site. I want to save it in a variable for further analyses.